# Monitor the server log of solr using a web interface

Tags: jakarta-ee, logging, solr, web

I've few servers in which I run solr indexing for a huge amount of data, right now I'm using putty to login to each server and then check the logs from there. I'm sure there is some way to do the same in a web interface for all the servers in a single page. Is there any open source tool to achieve the same?

Please Help

Thanks

Jeyaprakash

Comment: what does this have to do with programming?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions
Managing logs with a software tool commonly used by programmers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a self hosted, open source solution, then you might be able to use [graylog2](http://graylog2.org/).

Not open source, but you are willing to pay a bit for a payed solution, then [Papertrail](https://papertrailapp.com/) is a good hosted solution.